# Registering Service with /service command sometimes fails

Tags: service, cmd

I have a service I register using execuatableName.exe /service command line.
it usually succeeds but on some platforms it sometimes fails

following returns error code 9009 . any idea what can be the issue?

> MyService.exe /Service
>
> echo %errorlevel%

Answer (score 0):

CMD returns Errorlevel 9009 when the file cannot be found.